# How to communicate in Runtime between 2 computers (PC1, PC2) through PowerShell (via SSH) using subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, powershell, ssh, subprocess, popen

**Description of the situation:**

**PC1** is a Windows 10 computer. **PC2** is a computer with an Ubuntu operating system, on a very old version (12.04.5) which has a limited connection to the Internet (nothing can be installed on it). Also on it is a test system.

**The goal** is to create a script that controls in runtime all the inputs and outputs from PC2 during the running of the tests, because sometimes it is necessary for the user to intervene and enter test configuration data after which it can continue working.Output processing and writing to stdin must be automated.

**First attempt:**
In the first attempt, I wrote a main script, let's call it RuntimeListner.py, which starts several scripts with user input, which will have to be started one by one and all outputs are processed in runtime and when a user is needed input, then this script writes it with `Popen.stdin.write(bytes("command".encode()))`.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess


DATA_BANK_SCRIPTS = {
    "HelloUser": {
        "Please write your name:\r": "Stack",
        "Please write your age:\r": "99"
    },
    "AddTwoNumbers": {
        "Please write first number:\r": "10",
        "Please write second number:\r": "20",
    }
}

process = subprocess.Popen(["PowerShell.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for key, value_dict in DATA_BANK_SCRIPTS.items():
    script_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.joinpath(f"Tests\{key}.py")

    process.stdin.write(bytes(f"python {script_path}\n".encode()))
    process.stdin.flush()

    current_output = process.stdout.readline()
    while current_output:
        current_line = current_output.decode()
        current_line = current_line.rstrip("\n")
        print(current_line)

        if current_line in value_dict:
            process.stdin.write(bytes((value_dict[current_line] + '\n').encode()))
            process.stdin.flush()
            current_output = process.stdout.readline()
        else:    
            current_output = process.stdout.readline()
```

This demo script starts other scripts and waits until there is user input, after which it processes it and enters the data from the set dictionary.

**This is how the script version works. This works very well.**

**Second attempt:**

In the second attempt, I already want to have a separate PowerShell window, to have total control over it, so that I can take over all input/output from it.

```
powershell_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
process = subprocess.Popen(["start", powershell_path, "-ExecutionPolicy","Bypass","-NoExit"],cwd=r"C:\Windows\System32\\", shell=True,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This code block opens a new PowerSehll window, but further I can no longer call a script directly in this window and process input/output.

If I want to start any command in powershell then nothing is written.
For example:

```
process.stdin.write(bytes(f"python.exe {script_path}\n".encode()))
process.stdin.flush()
```

In the same way, nothing is written in the console and nothing is printed.

I also tried nested `subprocess.Popen`, by assigning stdin from the first process to the second process, but also no reaction. And also `stdout.readline()` freezes.

Is there another method to solve this problem? Maybe I'm wrong somewhere.